# Woocommerce best_selling_products shortcode not working

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, shortcode

Trying to add:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[products best_selling="true" limit="4"]'); ?>
```

In a template returns nothing. I see that no hooks are present for this but woocommerce says it should be supported.

Comment: Do you have any products that have sold? `best_selling` will only work if there are products that have sold better relative to the rest. If so, what version of WooCommerce are you using?

Comment: I have over 60 fake orders so I suppose this should be enough. The version is 3.4.4

Comment: @m33ts4k0z **This shortcode works** … Your 60 "Fake" orders need to be in a "completed" status, otherwise the shortcode will not give you anything.

Comment: Thanks but I have 10 on completed and still nothing shows

Comment: @m33ts4k0z You should delete this thread as it's not useful to anyone as *"this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced… While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this one because I came across another shortcode that wasn't working.

It turned out that the theme was the culprit. After switching to the default theme all shortcodes were working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this shortcode

```
[best_selling_products per_page="12"]
```

Please refer below link for Woocommerce Shortcodes

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: Thanks but still nothing